# error The "Login" component has been registered but not used vue/no-unused-components

Tags: javascript, vue.js, routes, vuetify.js, web-frontend

I am getting following error:
         The "Login" component has been registered but not used       vue/no-unused-components and 
       error  The "HelloWorld" component has been registered but not used  vue/no-unused-components.
       but why it is giving i am not getting any idea. i am new to vue.

```
router.js

import Vue from 'vue'
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
import Login from './components/Login.vue';
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue';

Vue.use(VueRouter)

export default new VueRouter({
    routes: [
        {
            path: '/',
            name: 'Login',
            component: Login
        },
        {
            path: '/helloworld',
            name: 'Helloworld',
           component: HelloWorld
        },
    ]
})

App.vue

 <template>
  <div id="app">
    <router-view></router-view>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Login from './components/Login.vue'
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue'

export default {
  name: 'App',
  components: {
      Login,
      HelloWorld
  }
}
</script>

<style>
#app {
  font-family: Avenir, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
   }
</style>
```

Comment: also main.js                                                                                                                                           import Vue from 'vue'
import App from './App.vue'
import vuetify from './plugins/vuetify';

Vue.config.productionTip = false

new Vue({
  vuetify,
  template: '<App/>',
  components: { App }
})

Answer (score 2):

In your App.vue you **don't** need to import Login and HelloWorld. This will be taken care of by the vue router in router.js file. You can remove below lines from your App.vue

```
<script>
import Login from './components/Login.vue' //remove this line
import HelloWorld from './components/HelloWorld.vue' //remove this line

...
...
components: {
      Login, //remove this line
      HelloWorld //remove this line
  }
....
```

Now, some information about the error that you have got because I am sure that you will be again getting this same error in other places of the project as you continue to develop. The error that you got is because of eslint found two variables that are not used anywhere in the file. Eslint helps to improve the code quality and reduce the bundle size by notifying many errors as you got. You can disable this particular lint by using.

```
<script>
/* eslint-disable vue/no-unused-components */
...
```

Or you can disable all eslint using `/* eslint-disable */` There are many other rules that you can apply for eslint check it here, https://eslint.org/docs/rules/

Comment: thank you error has gone and the app Compiled successfully but there is no view only blank web page. Why is it happening?

Comment: Did you mount the app? You need to import router to main.js and mount the same.